# datahub connects to hive, uses kerberos, occurred an error in web-ui

Tags: kerberos, datahub

When I was using the datahub ui for hive data ingestion, there was an exception that Could not connect to it

info:
[2024-02-04 08:11:42,352] INFO     {thrift.transport.TSocket:118} - Could not connect to ('69.167.164.199', 10000)

Here is my recipe.

source:
type: hive
config:
host_port: 'xxxxx.test.com:10000'
database: dm_prod
username: hive
include_views: false
stateful_ingestion:
ignore_old_state: true
enabled: true
database_pattern:
allow:
- dm_prod
table_pattern:
allow:
- 'dm_prod.*'
options:
connect_args:
auth: KERBEROS
kerberos_service_name: hive
scheme: hive+https
pipeline_name: ingest-scheduler-test

When I run this recipe on the cli, I can normally ingest hive data.
However, when I ingested the data through the web-ui, it could not be executed properly.
I'm curious, what's the problem with that, thank you

I try to find a solution, but so far, there is still no good solution

Answer (score 0):

```
source:
type: hive
config:
    host_port: 'xxxx.test.com:10000'
    database: dm_prod
    username: hive
    include_views: false
    stateful_ingestion:
        ignore_old_state: true
        enabled: true
    database_pattern:
        allow:
            - dm_prod
    table_pattern:
        allow:
            - dm_prod.*
    options:
        connect_args:
            auth: KERBEROS
            kerberos_service_name: hive
            scheme: hive+https
```

pipeline_name: 'ingest-test'

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).